# Need help retrieving a uri segment in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a `url` in CodeIgniter with an encrypted value. But when I try to get the `uri` segment CodeIgniter was not able to find it.

Is there anyway where i can use a prefix to find it?? Below is the url I am using

```
localhost/sandbox/index.php/client/applicants/applicantslist/index?proj=ijo7w%2BriCislarU8QCJZNXc7s7C3mI%2BVYoN49uFSf9U%3D/5

  //Set 11 for testing purposes
   $config['total_rows'] = 11;

    $config['per_page'] = 5;

    $config['num_links'] = 4;
    $config["prefix"] = "page=";

 // Showing nothing
    fb($this->uri->segment("5"));
```

Answer (score 0):

A segment is a part of the url itself, i.e. `index` is available or `applicantslist` is available.

Anything after the ? is within the scope of $_GET variables or with codeigniter `$this->input->get()`

It looks like you should be using `$this->input->get('proj')` in your case

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but that didn't work. I did a lot more googling and I found out the answer which I will post

Answer (score 0):

The answer that I came up with is by adding the get query string in the $config['suffix']  like so ...

```
$config['suffix'] = 'id?30'
```

The only problem with that is when I went back to the first page the it would just show the base url without the get params. In order to fix that I would do the following

```
   $config['first_url'] = $config['base_url'].'?'.http_build_query($_GET);
```

and that solved the problem!